# Generate WebService from WSDL in Spring, Maven (contract first)

Tags: spring, web-services, maven, wsdl, contract-first

*I want to create a contract first **Spring webservice***. So I have the WSDL file, but I can't find any example of generating the Spring webservices from the WSDL.

With this Maven plugin, I can generate it, but it will be a J2EE WebService, and not a Spring WebService, am I Right?:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <xdebug>true</xdebug>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <target>2.0</target>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-service</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <wsdlDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdls</wsdlDirectory>
                <wsdlFiles>
                    <wsdlFile>service.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                </wsdlFiles>
                <sourceDestDir>target/generated-code/src</sourceDestDir>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This will generate an interface, which has the **@WebService** annotation. But this **is** for the **J2EE** application, **and not Spring**, right?

> **So, is there any tool in maven for generate Spring WebServices from an
>   already written WSDL file?**

Because I cannot find any, only the jaxws-Maven-plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can surely use :

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html

or http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.2/example_xjc_basic.html

or even https://java.net/projects/maven-jaxb2-plugin/pages/Home

Then you'll just have to create a jaxws:client in spring :
http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-ws-configuration.html

Or just the cxf component in camel :
http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html

J2EE is nothing more than a stack, a collection of framework that forms a collection. You can use CXF/Spring with another Framework (such as OSGi) and just import what interests you (for example, camel-cxf, spring-core, ...). For example, I'm working on an OSGi environment, but we are using codegen plugin to generate the class and then integrate them with camel-cxf.

Comment: But this cxf-codegen-plugin will create @WebService annotations for the interfaces too. Is this good for Spring application? Isn't it J2EE architect?

Comment: J2EE is nothing more than a stack, a collection of framework that forms a collection. You can use CXF/Spring with another Framework (such as OSGi) and just import what interests you (for example, camel-cxf, spring-core, ...).

For example, I'm working on an OSGi environment, but we are using codegen plugin to generate the class and then integrate them with camel-cxf.

Comment: JavaEE, not J2EE because that's been retired for a decade now, is a set of specifications forming one verifiable standard for a JavaEE application server. The implementations of that standard - Wildfly, Glassfish, TomEE, etc. are the true stacks.